# Bad variant cast exception when converting a Javascript object to a JSAPIPtr

Tags: javascript, c++, com, firebreath

I am initialising a Javascript object and passing it to a registered API function whose signature is as follows::

I checked that the variant object coming from Javascript is not empty....

***JS file***

Initialize function called when I press a button...

```
 function Initialize() 
    {
        var Class=function(){this.member1_JS='Red'};
        BorderStyle.prototype.member2_JS='1';
        var obj=new Class();
        plugin().DoTheChanges(obj);

    }
```

=======================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
_jsObjPtr= objectFromJavaScript.convert_cast<FB::JSObjectPtr>();
```

Any object coming from javascript is a JSObjectPtr; if it's doing a convert_cast to JSAPIPtr it will try to find inside the JSObjectPtr a C++ JSAPI object that you have created (for example, a DicomAPI object) which won't actually work on most browsers because they hide it too deep to get back out.

Comment: can i cast a FB::variant to a c++ class pointer extending FB::JSAPIAuto? I tried ..but its throwing bad variant cast. is there any other way?

Comment: It depends on what is inside it, but probably not; thing is, when the JSAPI object goes to the page it gets wrapped in something before it is sent back on many browsers so you can't get the underlying type back out of it. I recommend assigning every instance of your object a unique id and storing a weak_ptr to it in a global std::map<int, boost::weak_ptr<yourJsapiType> > or something similar; then you call `->Invoke("getId", FB::variant_list_of()).convert_cast<int32_t>();` on it (you have to add the getId method) and use that int to get the object.

Comment: I found a way to get past this exception(Please see the edit),but I am encountering a System Violation exception while accessing a COM component while doing this way.Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm losing track of the thread; if you need a discussion, better to ask on the google group, if it's a new question, ask a new question